# Comparison test for proving convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> I'm trying to determine whether this series is convergent or divergent:
> $$
> \sum_1^\infty \frac{e^{1/n}-1}{n}
> $$

I thought directly that $e^{1/n} \geq 1$ and therefore $\frac{e^{1/n}-1}{n} \geq \frac{1}{n}$, then using comparison test $\frac{e^{1/n}-1}{n}$ is divergent since $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, but apparently it converges!
But I can't find what's wrong with my solution!

Comment: $e^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq 1$ implies that $e^{\frac{1}{n}} -1 \geq 0$, not $ \geq 1$ as you seem to be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $e^{1/n}>1$.  Then, it is true that $e^{1/n}-1>0$, but not true that $e^{1/n}-1>1$.

However, we do have for $n>1$, $e^{1/n}-1\le \frac1{1-1/n}-1=\frac1{n-1}$ (See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)).  And clearly

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n-1}-\frac1n=1$$ converges.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is large
$$a_n=\frac{e^{\frac 1n}-1}n=\frac 1{n^2}+\frac{1}{2 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$  Compare with $p$ series.